# Firefox version 53.0.3 (32-bit) does not support my material lite design

Tags: css, firefox, material-design

I open my localhost app in

- Chrome  - working perfectly
- Edge - working but some css not supported
- Mozilla Firefox version 53.0.3 (32-bit) - White screen.

Now why it's become white screen on Mozilla? Any ideas? Here is my codes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:2001/assets/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script src="http://localhost:2001/assets/material.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .remove-padding{
            padding:0px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Population</title>
</head>
<body>
<dialog class="mdl-dialog remove-padding">
        <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--6dp">
            <form method="post" action="http://localhost:2001/login/process">
                    <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--primary mdl-color-text--white">
                        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Login</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="email" required id="email" name="email" value="" />
                                                                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="email">Email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" required id="userpass" name="password" />
                                                                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="userpass">Password</label>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border" style="text-align: right;">
                        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                            Sign In
                        </button>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</dialog>
<script>
    var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
    dialog.showModal();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: None...no errors.

Comment: @Ryan it return one error --> `ERROR - 2017-06-01 00:25:08 --> 404 Page Not Found --> `

Comment: @Ryan why this happened?When I view source, the code was there.

Comment: Look in your network panel. How many requests are there? Which ones are highlighted in red?

Comment: None..no red colors

Comment: For this time I need to modify the code become
`<dialog class="mdl-dialog remove-padding" style="display:block">` since I realized that `var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
    dialog.showModal();` does not executed in Mozilla. White screen solved! But in messy ways...waiting for another best answers.